# Camel-JPA: mark as entity as consumed (without updating table record)

Tags: jpa, apache-camel

I am stuck (again ;-) with some JPA related problem and hope that anyone here can help (Camel in Action couldn't...):

I consume from a JPA endpoint using a namedQuery.
I cannot delete consumed entries, thus I am using the "consumeDelete=false" option.

But how can I prevent reading the same entry multiple times?
I am aware of the "@consumed" annotation, but since I am not allowed to modify/update the original database entries, I haven't figured out how I can mark a entry as "consumed"...

Any ideas?

thanks,
M

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot change the data in the database anyhow to reflect that you have consumed the record already, then you would need to "store" this information elsewhere.

You can use the idempotent consumer EIP pattern
http://camel.apache.org/idempotent-consumer.html

You would then need to use a memory/file/another database/table to store id's of already consumed messages, and use that with the idempotent consumer pattern.

Comment: Thanks Claus! I read about idempotent consumer in "Camel In Action" (great book btw). Will look into the approach suggested by u! just thought there might be some work around (e.g. using @consumed on a transient property, or something like that...)

Comment: Hi again, implemented the idempotent Consumer now using the in-memory repository (MemoryIdempotentRepository). It works fine until now, thanks again! just wondering how many entries the in-memory repo can handle. do u have some experience on that? greetings, M

Comment: I think you can set a upper limit on the memory repo. It uses a default of 1000 entries. And it uses a LRU based cache.

Answer (score -1):

You can use @Consumed in your entity class with any method name and change the value of field to your desire value. for example

```
@Consumed
public void updateConsumedStatus() {
this.status = false;
}
```

Please check here too
http://camel.apache.org/jpa.html